# Make "Pick up at store" function in checkout layout file

Tags: magento2, checkout, overrides

I'm about to override checkout phtml file and also make a javascript file which allows the change of shipping method when a customer choose "pick up at store".

Let me show you what i am supposed to make.

[image]

**1. I will make a button for pick up at store right next to shipping address section on checkout page**

**2. Below the shipping methods, there are still 2 shipping methods. But when a customer choose real shipping address like first and second one, i want to show them only flat rate. But if a customer choose pick up at store, only free shipping method should be shown as a shipping method. And it is made with free shipping based on megento basic function.**

- I think that a javascript file needs in this part. I'm so pooor at js tho.

What should i do first in order to implement this process. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this would require customization of the some of the web assets of the Checkout Module.

Linking a reference module which you could perhaps refer to while building this functionality

Knowledge of the following things are recommended
a) Extension attributes
b) Knockout Js (Atleast the Basics)
c) Component structure in XML (Quite easy, just refer to the checkout_index_index.xml file being shared)
d) Plugin

Below is the link
https://github.com/Smile-SA/magento2-module-store-delivery

P.S.
I would recommend installing this module on a fresh Magento2 setup using composer and check.

Let me know if you need any further help on this.